# Masking fragments generated by gl_PointSize

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, shader

I'm trying to mask out some particles made with points so that they don't render on some areas of my scene but I can't seem to be able to get the fragment shader right, this is what I have so far:

```
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
uniform sampler2D tStencil;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D( tDiffuse, vTexCoord );
    vec4 stencil = texture2D(tStencil, gl_FragCoord.xy);
    gl_FragColor = stencil * diffuseColor;
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
attribute float size;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    vec3 vertex = position;
    vTexCoord = vTexCoordRef;
    gl_PointSize = size;
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( vertex, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

Shader output:

[image: Shader output]

Stencil texture:

[image: Stencil texture]

Desired output made in paint:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the part you are missing is the texture coordinate for `tStencil`. If that texture is the same size as tDiffuse, then you can use the same `vTexCoord` for both.

```
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
uniform sampler2D tStencil;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;
varying vec2 vTexCoord2; // a texture coord for the stencil

void main() {
   vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D( tDiffuse, vTexCoord );
   vec4 stencil = texture2D(tStencil, vTexCoord2);
   gl_FragColor = stencil * diffuseColor;
}
```

If all is well there, you may want to look at your alpha values. If your point cloud is composed of the white points in the middle of the image with black clear color all around, then you want your stencil to render as an alpha channel. Do a conditional so that wherever your stencil image texels occur (whatever color or alpha they are), set the alpha of your gl_FragColor to 0.0. That should punch through the white of your point cloud to reveal the black clear color.

```
gl_FragColor = vec4( (gl_FragColor * diffuseColor).rgb, alphaBasedOnStencil );
```

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions but it didn't work. I still get the same result. All textures are the same size for what is worth.

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - what are your alpha values? You will need `tStencil`'s to be 1.0, and if `tDiffuse`'s is 0.0, and is multiplied against `tStencil`'s alpha, the stencil will be clear and you won't see it. You may want to multiply only the xyz and explicitly set the alpha to 1.0.

Comment: setting the alpha manually after multiplying the xyz didn't change anything either. Could it be something weird with the point system?

Comment: ...and conditionally set that alpha to 1.0 in cases where the multiplied xyz produces black (0.0, 0.0, 0.0).

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - are there points in this shader, or was the point cloud produced by a previous shader that wrote out `tDiffuse`?

Comment: tDiffuse is a renderTarget of my scene, the points were created through the particle system like so: var particleSystem = new THREE.Points( geometry, particleMaterial ); The shaders above are the ones declared in the particleMaterial. Hence each particle is running this shader.

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - If there are points in this shader, you'll want to account for them by multiplying the existing frag color (your points) against the results of your two textures `gl_FragColor = vec4( ( gl_FragColor * (stencil * diffuseColor)).xyz, preCheckedAlpha )`

Comment: After this bit of code I couldn't see anything, everything was black. Changing the clear color to white revealed it's still the same but opposite color (white is black and black is white) as the first image above.

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - are the particles the white shape in the middle, or the black shape around the edge?

Comment: White color in the middle, alpha all around.

Comment: Ah! Then if your point cloud is composed of white points in the middle, then you want your stencil to render as an alpha channel. Do a conditional so that wherever the stencil texels (xyz) are black, set the alpha of your gl_FragColor to 0.0. That should punch through the white of your point cloud to reveal the black clear color.

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - see above

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - I should ask what color your person image is. The idea is that wherever it is  - whether the pixels are black, white, opaque or whatever, you use that information to trigger a conditional that makes any texel that occurs in the person image result in a 0.0 alpha in your gl_FragColor.

Comment: setting the alpha doesn't seem to work. My guess from what I'm experimenting with it, is that the UVs are not correct. Not sure why that is. I've tried all kinds of values in the reading of the stencil texture but none seem to give the correct value.

Comment: I just tested that the UVs are wrong by doing a simple test, trying to output the background color in the particles and as I suspected the output is not the background image when using vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy; it's like the UVs are trying to access outside of the texture and I can see some details but the rest is color bleed. I've double checked that all my RT are the same size.

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - Try using the built in `uv`: https://threejs.org/docs/api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.html

Comment: is `resolution` really injected by three by default? I didnt know that, and cant find it in the sources.

Comment: @pailhead - see the link above

Comment: I'm not actually seeing resolution?  This link?
http://threejs.org/docs/api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.html

Comment: @pailhead - oh, indeed. It's missing. See this example instead: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_gpgpu_birds.html

Comment: @pailhead  - Oops. Sorry, that appears to be specific to GPUComputationRenderer. I'll edit above.

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - see the change reflected in the comments above, that may solve your uv problem.

Comment: It's not a big deal, i use this pattern a lot but not all the shaders need it, so i was a bit surprised when i read it's injecting into all of them :)

Comment: I had another underlying issue as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827826/gl-fragcoord-doesnt-match-the-size-of-the-screen-in-three-js. Once I fixed that, setting the alpha value as the stencil value fixed the issue.

Comment: @RobertRodriguez - Yay - congratulations! I'll add my alpha comments to the answer above, if you could please click to accept!